# modify rmarkdown chunk output without loosing cache?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I've run a time consuming rmarkdown chunk and i would like to change the output so warnings are no longer shown. Is there a way to change warning=TRUE to warning=FALSE in the chuck options and avoid having to rerun the chunck?

thanks
I.

Comment: You could open the actual html file and edit that

Answer (score 0):

````
```{r, warning = FALSE}
```
````

This will hide warnings that get generated when the chunk is ran. I don't believe you can hide the warnings after it's ran without rerunning it. Or if your output was HTML, you could remove the warnings in the HTML source code.

Comment: It's `warning` not `warnings`, and this will stop then when the chunk is run, but per the actual question it doesn't remove them when after the chunk is run, only when it is re-run.